# Dropdown populated from database doesn't record selected option with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

what is wrong with my code below?
I don't know how to say to my SQL INSERT to record the selected option of the dropdown.
I've edited my question so someone could help me more with this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?php
    $usuarioLogado = $_SESSION['email'];
    $etapa = "semana1";
    $showModal = false;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM campeonato WHERE usuario = '$usuarioLogado' AND etapa = '$etapa'";
    $ref = $select_db->query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ref);

    if(isset($_POST['time']) && isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $showModal = true;
        $times = $_POST["time"];
        $dobrada = $_POST["dobrada"];
        $sobrevivente = $_POST["sobrevivente"];
        if ($row) {
            $sql = "UPDATE campeonato SET ";
            foreach ($times as $time => $valor) {
                if ($valor != null) {
                    $sql .= "$time = $valor,";
                }
            }
            $sql .= " dobrada = $dobrada, sobrevivente = $sobrevivente, datahora = now() WHERE usuario = '$usuarioLogado' AND etapa = '$etapa'";

            if ($select_db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                //echo "Dados atualizados com sucesso";
            } else {
                //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $select_db->error;
            }
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO campeonato (datahora, usuario, etapa, dobrada, sobrevivente,";
            foreach ($times as $time => $valor) {
                if ($valor != null) {
                    $sql .= "$time,";
                }
            }
            $sql = substr_replace($sql ,"", -1);
            $sql .= ") VALUES (now(), '$usuarioLogado', '$etapa', $dobrada, $sobrevivente,";
            foreach ($times as $time => $valor) {
                if ($valor != null) {
                    $sql .= "$valor,";
                }
            }
            $sql = substr_replace($sql ,"", -1);
            $sql .= ")";
            if ($select_db->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                //echo "Dados cadastrados com sucesso";
            } else {
                //echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $select_db->error;
            }
        }
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM campeonato WHERE usuario = '$usuarioLogado' AND etapa = '$etapa'";
    $ref = $select_db->query($query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ref);
?>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="quantity">
                    <input name="time[time1]" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" value="<?=$row["time1"]?>" required />
                    <input name="time[time2]" type="number" min="0" max="99" step="1" value="<?=$row["time2"]?>" required />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                    <select name="dobrada" required style="color: #000;">
                        <option value=""> - Selecione A - </option>
                        <?php
                            for ($i = 1; $i <= 16; $i++) {
                                if ($row["DOBRADA"] == $i) {
                                    echo "<option value='$i' selected=selected>Jogo $i</option>";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<option value='$i'>Jogo $i</option>";
                                }
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                    <select name="sobrevivente" required style="color: #000;">
                        <option value=""> - Selecione B - </option>
                        <?php
                            $queryS = "SELECT * FROM lista_times";
                            $resultS = $select_db->query($queryS);
                            while ($list = $resultS->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                                echo "<option value='".$list['times']."'>".$list['times']."</option>";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="full-area">
                <td class="text-center" colspan="6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" style="color: #000;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
```

Hello friends, what is wrong with my code below?
I don't know how to say to my SQL INSERT to record the selected option of the dropdown.
I've edited my question so someone could help me more with this.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code itself, this code is only rendering the selectbox, but to insert you need to write more parts. is this is what you are asking about?

Comment: you may benefit from reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900731/5561431)

Comment: @AhmedNasr Yes I know, the code is correct and it can render the selectbox ok. But when user selects one option listed, I need to get this value and send it to the insert, like this: 
$sql = "INSERT INTO libertadores2019 (datahora, usuario, etapa, dobrada, sobrevivente,";

Comment: you can trigger a javascript onchange event in the select box

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which shows how you try to insert a new row into the database, based on the selection of the dropdown list. Currently you are only showing the source code which generates the content of the dropdown list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, but no one was correct.
I've made it! The problem was with missing quotations.

Answer (score 3):

PHP code runs when the client (e.g., a browser) makes a request. Selecting an element from a dropdown doesn't make any requests (the page has already loaded), and thus there is no PHP code whatsoever that can achieve this with the page in its current state.

You have two options:

- Add some JavaScript code to the page that triggers when a new element is selected, which makes an AJAX request to your server when that happens; or
- Add a button to submit the form. Submitting the form will send a request (typically a `POST` request) to the server for whatever page you specify in the `<form>` element. You'd have to handle the `INSERT` from that page, using the data submitted by the form.

The latter option seems to fit your use case better. At this stage, I'd recommend doing some research on how forms work and how you can handle them from PHP.

Comment: this was a generic answer

Comment: @RodrigoLinkweb Any answer to such a broad question that you get will be "generic" in some way. We're not going to write the page for you; that's not what SO is for. You can't add an `INSERT` to your current code because that's not how PHP works — thus, I'm explaining how to achieve what you want. Do your research! If you get stuck later on in some particular step, you'll have a specific question you can ask and get a specific answer for. Right now you asked a question that turned out to be generic, and thus any answer will be just as generic.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a change event occur on the select box, you can use the Ajax call to send the data to the server and get the response from that.

You can use the Jquery library for making ajax call.

Add the Id to select tag

```
<select name="sobrevivente" id="sobrevivente" required style="color: #000;">
<option value=""> - Selecione 1 time sobrevivente - </option>
<?php
    $queryS = "SELECT * FROM libertadores_times";
    $resultS = $select_db->query($queryS);
    while ($list = $resultS->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        echo "<option value='".$list['times']."'>".$list['times']."</option>";
    }
?>
```

```
<!-- Jquery CDN Link (Jquery Library)-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // based on the change event this section will be triggered
    $("body").on('change', '#sobrevivente', function() {
       var sobrevivente = $(this).val();
      var post_data = {
         sobrevivente: sobrevivente
      }
      var url = 'https://someurl.com/filename'
      $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url : url,
            data : post_data,
            success: function(response){
                // Handling the response                
            }
        })
   });
</script>
```

url : https://someurl.com/filename 
-- Place where you can write the process to insert the data and echo out the result process in a json format.

```
<?php
    $category_id = $_POST['sobrevivente'];

    // your code to insert it into the database

    if($success){
        $ajax_response = "success";
    }
    else
    {
        $ajax_response = "failed";
    }
    echo json_encode($ajax_response);
?>
```